# how to display $page array?

Tags: 7, theming

How to display the entire $page array like shown below? 
I have devel module installed and have tried "dsm($page)" but that just shows the word "Array".

[image]

Comment: If `dsm($page)` just shows an array, then the variable named `$page` in that context is an empty array. Either that or you have a broken version of Devel/Krumo. Or, you haven't actually called `dsm()`, but `drupal_set_message()`, which is an altogether different function, and doesn't format arrays/objects automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can try dsm($page) in page.tpl.php of your theme to see the contents of $page array.

As mentioned by Clive, context really matters. If you will try to print $page array when it has no elements then it will display word Array.